# Making circles given centres and radii in Python skimage

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-image

I have three arrays: one contains the centre of a circle, one contains the radius of the circle and one contains the ID of the circle.

The ID refers to a 128x128 array on which the circles should be drawn and on any ID there can be 1 or many circles.

There is a command to draw_polygons in the skimage library, called draw_circles.

I am struggling with cycling through the IDs and matching them up the centres and radii in the other two arrays.

I have a data frame which stores the information and the arrays are below:

```
allIDs = getNumpyArrayFromPandas(data, ['Id'])

allCentreXY = getNumpyArrayFromPandas(data, ['centre x', 'centre y'])

allRadii = getNumpyArrayFromPandas(data, ['radius'])
```

[image: The Id is in the second column and the centre the third and the radius the fourth]

i.e there will be 7 circles drawn for the first ID (4000), 6 circles drawn for the next ID (4001) etc.

I have tried

```
def draw_one_circle(img, one_circle):
    radius = one_circle[0]
    centre = one_circle[1]
    rr, cc = disk(centre, radius,(128,128))
    img[rr,cc] = 1

def draw_circles(img, circles):
    for circle in circles:
        draw_one_polygon(img, circle)

circles = read_input(x)
img = np.zeros((128, 128), dtype=np.uint8)
draw_polygons(img, circles)
```

but I don't know how to read the coordinates in from the arrays

Answer (score 1):

To get the coordinates, you can iterate over the three arrays in parallel, using [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip):

```py
for ident, centre, radius in zip(allIDs, allCentreXY, allRadii):
    # Draw one circle with these values.
```